# Proof on relationship between generators and order of a cyclic group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

[image]

Why do we have $a^{nq} = e$ in this proof?

Answer (score 1):

For any element $\;a\;$ of a group of order $\;n\;$ we have by Lagrange's theorem that

$$a^n=e\implies a^{nq}=\left(a^n\right)^q=e^q=e$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is there any way to keep this proof more elementary? By this point of the textbook we haven't got to Lagrange's theorem yet.

Comment: @ensbana This is terribly elementary...and I really can't understand on what could that book (which one, btw?) be relying to justify $\;a^{nq}=e\;$ other than Lagrange's theorem...

Comment: It's on page 47 of this book. http://abstract.ups.edu/download/aata-20170805.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> "Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $n$ (...)"

You assume that $G$ is a cyclic group of order $n$, so $a^{nq}=\left (a^n\right )^q=e^q=e$ by definition.